# parsing and iterating over a large dataset - why are these results not lining up? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, dataset, iteration

I have a question about my JavaScript (vanilla JS, no library answers please).

**setup**

- I have two `.txt` files, `names` and `data`.
- `names` contains a list of 100 last names, one name per line, ie:

> ```
> Nader
> Sanford
> Kovacek
> Lynch
> etc...
> ```

- `data` contains a much longer list, of first names, last names, a comma and a value, ie:

> ```
> Kailee Huel,2
> Arianna Runolfsson,4
> Marshall Kuhn,3
> Cristina Huel,4
> Garnett Medhurst,3
> etc...
> ```

**task**

Iterate through `data.txt` using the last names in `names.txt`. If any of the last names from `names.txt` have a match in `data.txt`, increment a counter with the value on that line (after the comma). Some last names are repeated in both `names.txt` and `data.txt`.

**problem I am encountering**:

I have been given that my sample data set must return a value of `443`, however the result I am getting is `500`. this tells me I am making a blunder with my processing somewhere in my code below.

**my code**:

```
// doc rdy
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if( document.readyState == "complete" ){
    init();
  }
}

// setup
function init(){
  var base      = "data/sample/",
      namesFile = base+"names.txt",
      dataFile  = base+"data.txt";

  loadFile(namesFile, function(e){
    names = e;
    loadFile(dataFile, function(ev){
      processData(ev);
    });
  });
}


function processData(e){
  var counter = 0;
  // for each last name,
  for( var i=0; i<names.length; i++ ){
    // if "data object" contains "this name", add its val to counter
    if( e.hasOwnProperty(names[i]) ){
      // console.log( 'match: ' + names[i] );
      counter += e[names[i]];
    }
  }

  // The Final Output:
  console.log(counter);
}


// ajax loading
function loadFile( filename, callback ){
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var result;
  client.open('GET', filename);
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( client.readyState==4 && client.status==200 ){
      result = client.responseText.split("\n");
      // custom handling for the data set..
      if( result[0].search(',') !== -1 ){
        result = arrCSVtoObj(result);
      }

      callback(result);
    }
  }
  client.send();
}


// converts an array of CSV to a key:value object
function arrCSVtoObj(csvArr) {
  var obj = {};

  // for each line in the array,
  for( var i=0; i<csvArr.length; i++ ){
    // split into key:value on comma
    var split = csvArr[i].split(",");
    var key =  getLastName(split[0]);
    var val = parseInt(split[1]);

    // assign the new property to the object
    if( ! obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
      obj[key] = val;
    }else{
      obj[key] += val;
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

function getLastName(e){
  var nameArr = e.split(" ");
  return nameArr[1];
}
```

**question**:
What in the above code could be causing my result to return higher than anticipated?

========

**EDIT**:

Here is the sample data I am using. It is returning a value of "500" when it should be returning a value of "443".

- [names.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tconroy/5d7ad440ca74d131731e/raw/b499a6ac79ee9b8956a83ee253aff010ed8fae01/names.txt)
- [data.txt](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tconroy/b784c65e34ef22e07981/raw/853dae2dfb1a8663fbea98a965aaebd571bb2b1b/data.txt)

Comment: Can you show a specific set of sample data, the expected result, and the actual result you're getting instead?

Comment: Probably you'll be a step closer to the answer by using this line `console.log( 'match: ' + names[i] + '- counter is: ' + counter);` as the last statement in the `if` clause of your `processData` function

Comment: @Barmar: I have added links to the sample data I am using at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Tyblitz: I am unsure as to what you mean. I have done that, and the output looks right as far as I can tell without going through and manually adding the values myself to double-check. There's nothing obviously wrong with the output. There has to be a better way to debug this than manually adding thousands of data points together?

Comment: Can you make a **smaller** sample set, so we can try to analyze it by hand?

Comment: @Barmar: when I use just a chunk of the data set I am getting the correct value, the problem arises only when using the full data set. If I just crop, say, 10 names and 100 values, the answer is correct.

Comment: My guess is that you're not taking some duplicates into account when you're calculating the expected value.

Comment: @Barmar: I was thinking that it had to do with duplicates as well. I imagine I'd have to make a change inside the `arrCSVtoObj()` method but I'm unsure as to what needs to be changed. Currently I am checking if the name exists in the object first, if it does then the existing value is incremented, if it does not then the name is added and the value is assigned.

Comment: I just tried doing the same calculation using `awk`, and the result I got was 500.

Comment: I get 443 if I remove all duplicate names from `names.txt` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a name appears in `names.txt` multiple times, you're adding it to the counter each time. If you don't want to do that, you need to keep track of which names you've already processed, and skip them when they occur again:

```
var namesProcessed = {};

function processData(e){
    var counter = 0;
    // for each last name,
    for( var i=0; i<names.length; i++ ){
        // if "data object" contains "this name", add its val to counter
        if( e.hasOwnProperty(names[i]) && !namesProcessed.hasOwnProperty(names[i]) ){
            // console.log( 'match: ' + names[i] );
            counter += e[names[i]];
            namesProcessed[names[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    // The Final Output:
    console.log(counter);
}
```

If you're using a library like jQuery or Underscore.js, they provide functions to get the unique elements of a list: `$.unique()` and `_.uniq()`. Use this on the `names` array before iterating.

Comment: Brilliant. For some reason I thought I was just adding 0 when duplicates were encountered but as you pointed out I was actually re-adding all the values. This worked perfect. Thanks.

Comment: You were only checking for duplicates in `data.txt`, not in `names.txt`.